# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSFMCSdk.isPushEnabled')

Tags: marketing-cloud, react-native, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I am integrating Marketing Cloud SDK in react native, using react-native-marketingcloudsdk

```
"react-native-marketingcloudsdk": "8.1.0",
```

Accessing Native module using following react native code,

```
import MCReactModule, {CustomEvent} from 'react-native-marketingcloudsdk';
let enabled = await MCReactModule.isPushEnabled();
let systemToken = await MCReactModule.getSystemToken();
```

It's working fine in iOS, getting values for `enabled` and `systemTooken` in iOS, but in android getting following error,

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSFMCSdk.isPushEnabled')
```